# Implementing filter design using LabVIEW

Tags: filtering, labview

I am currently starting to learn LabVIEW for a project. It seems very new (and alien) to me. 
I need to do filter design using LabVIEW. I have the filter in the form of :
y(n) = y(n-1)+y(n-2)..... + 1/23[x(n-1)+.......]

Given an equation of that kind, how would I implement the filter? I have tried options like Advanced Signal Processing Toolkit and so on; but couldn't find the necessary block.

Kindly reply at the earliest. Any suggestions are welcome as well.

Comment: Have a look at the point by point filters and the forward / reverse coefficients

Comment: Will do and get back to you :)

Comment: Found it. It works fine. However, I have a derivative operation I need to perform. It has a difference equation of the form : y(n) = x(n-1)+.....
How would I implement that?

Comment: Do it in C# and import into Labview?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to implement a similar filter.

**My attempt:**

[image: Equation of the filter]

[image: Block diagram of the filter]

I do not know if this is the best way to implement such a filter however it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for editing my comment! How could I have inserted the images as inline from the beginning?